# One way synonym search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, type-synonyms

I want to implement synonym one way search in Elasticsearch. One way search meaning if I define a => x,y,z and search for 'a', search result should include all the documents containing words x,y,z,a which is working now. But if I search for 'x' then search result should contain document which contains only 'x' and not 'a'.

Is this possible in Elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this in a synonym relation as the behaviour you are explaining is a `hyperonym`/`hyponym` relation.

You can achieve such a behaviour on `index-time` though.

So for each occurrence of `a` you also index `x,y,z`. Using an additional field for this would be a good idea to not mess up the scores.

This behaviour is sadly not part of elasticsearch and has to be implemented by hand while feeding the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented one-way synonyms by inverting the synonym expression:

e.g.:

```
Robert => Bob, Rob
Bob => Robert
```

but I had to use this analyzer with synonyms is different way.
In mapping, synonyms are hooked to a new field:

```
"FirstName": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "search_analyzer": "standard",
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "standard"
    },
    "synonym": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "firstname_synonym_analyzer"
    }
  }
},
```

And search looks like this:

```
 "bool": {
    "should": [
       {
          "match": {
             "FirstName": {
                "query": "Jo"
             }
          }
       },
       {
          "match": {
             "FirstName.synonym": {
                "query": "Jo"
             }
          }
       }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
 }
```

This way first field contains normal value, second just possible synonyms. So looking for `Bob` finds `Robert`, but not `Rob`.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it with synonyms using `generic expansion` aka `genre expansion` and different analyzers for index-time and query-time

Synonyms at **index time**:

```
Bob => Bob, Robert
Rob => Rob, Robert
```

The format is like

```
word => the same word, more generic word, even more generic, etc
```

**Query time**: no synonyms applied

Query for "Bob" will return only documents where "Bob" was.

Query for "Rob" will return only documents where "Rob" was.

Query for "Robert" will return documents where "Bob", "Rob" and "Robert" was.

Comment: In your case the 'a' was the most generic term, so the definitions are like x=> x, a; y => y, a; z => z, a